# Active Directory not working for offsite

Tags: c#, active-directory

**Technology used:  asp.net(C#), MVC, LINQ, Entity**

I use the Active Directory for our company website.  This system works for all of our employees on site and when we take our laptop offsite and use VPN.

However we recently hired some developers(offsite) who we have given VPN access to.  But they are unable to run our code and I am unsure why.  We have active directory users set up for them and they can connect to us through VPN.

They are running into two errors.

A username/password error.
The Server is not Operational error.

Does the VPN username/password have to match the active directory account?
If they log into their development machine does that username/password have to match the active directory account?

Is there some restriction on Active Directory and offsite I am unaware of as to why this would work for us but not our off site developers?

Below is the section of code that is giving the error:  It errors on the line `SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();`

```
public AD_CurrentUserProfile GetUserProfile(string userName)
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.com"))
            using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de))
            {
                ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

                ds.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(samaccountname=" + userName + "))");
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("directreports");

                SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();

                AD_CurrentUserProfile userProfile = new AD_CurrentUserProfile();

                userProfile.currentUser = GetProfileFromDN(rs.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString());
                userProfile.managerProfile = GetProfileFromDN(rs.Properties["manager"][0].ToString(), true);

                int departmentID = db.IPACS_Department.First(v => (v.name == userProfile.currentUser.department)).departmentID;
                userProfile.ipacs_department = db.IPACS_Department.Find(departmentID);

                if (userProfile.currentUser.userName == userProfile.ipacs_department.owner)
                {
                    userProfile.currentUser.isManager = true;
                }

                // Override for Provana and upper management
                if (userProfile.currentUser.department == "Provana" || userProfile.currentUser.department == "JM")
                {
                    userProfile.currentUser.isManager = true;
                }

                if (rs.Properties["DirectReports"].Count > 0)
                {
                    if (!userProfile.currentUser.isManager)
                    {
                        userProfile.currentUser.isSupervisor = true;
                    }
                    userProfile.directReports = new HashSet<AD_User>();

                    foreach (string value in rs.Properties["DirectReports"])
                    {
                        userProfile.directReports.Add(GetProfileFromDN(value));
                    }
                }

                return userProfile;
            }
        }
```

I never pass 'password' anywhere in any of my code, so is this something Active Directory does by default?

Comment: Are you getting their username from the currently logged in user on the workstation? If they aren't logged into the workstation through the domain, I could see the usernames not matching causing weird things.

Comment: @StevenV I made it so I can pass in a custom username.  So I am passing in a username that matches their specific active directory account.  I'm not sure if it is somehow grabbing a password and trying to use that, or if the server is not operational error is also causing an authentication error.

Comment: I'm kind of assuming this is a desktop application. If the user is authenticated through the domain, the user account has enough permissions to query against Active Directory. But if the user is logged in through the workstation without the domain, that local user account does not have enough permissions to query against active directory and would need to provide credentials to query against Active Directory.

Comment: @StevenV Sorry this is a web application, I'll update the OP with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection to AD will always require windows credentials. Your code, as posted, does not supply any credentials to AD. (You pass in a user name that you are looking up, but that is not the same as supplying credentials for the connection). This will work for users whose machines are attached to the domain...because your network credentials are passed in implicitly. For the external devs, when they VPN in, they supply credentials to the VPN protocol, which allows their machines to access your network, but that doesn't mean their machines are 'joined' to the domain...so AD will still require explicit credentials from them, including a personal password or a service account password that has permissions to access AD.

This line:

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.com"))
```

essentially needs to allow a user name and password:

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.com"), userName, pwd)
{
  de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None | AuthenticationTypes.ReadonlyServer;
}
```

...you'll have to experiment with the AuthenticationTypes flags depending on how your network admins have it set up.